# I am trying to connect ps3 controller to Arduino mega using usb host shield, but it isn't getting?

Tags: wireless, remote-control

I tried various method from YouTube and also debugged it. It shows that ps3 controller address was set to local Bluetooth address, after that when I try to connect, it shows that it is receiving request from controller but however the request isn't getting completed

```
PS3 Bluetooth Library Started
PS3 Bluetooth Library Started
Bluetooth Dongle Initialized
HCI Reset complete
Write class of device
Local Bluetooth Address: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:10
Wait For Incoming Connection Request
Incoming Connection Request
Remote Name: Pro Controller
Connection Failed: 08
Connection Failed: 08
Connection Failed: 08
Connection Failed: 08
Connection Failed: 08
Wait For Incoming Connection Request
HCI Disconnected from Device
Wait For Incoming Connection Request
Connection Failed: 13
Connection Failed: 13
```

when I try to reset ps3 controller address, it shows that address was reset.

```
PS3 Bluetooth Library Started
Bluetooth Dongle Initialized
HCI Reset complete
Write class of device
Local Bluetooth Address: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:10
Wait For Incoming Connection Request
PS3 Bluetooth Library Started
PS3 Bluetooth Library Started
Bluetooth Dongle Initialized
HCI Reset complete
Write class of device
Local Bluetooth Address: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:10
Wait For Incoming Connection Request
setAddr: 0E
BTD Init Failed, error code: 0E

Dualshock 3 Controller Connected
Bluetooth Address was set to: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:10
Bluetooth Dongle Initialized
HCI Reset complete
Write class of device
Local Bluetooth Address: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:10
Wait For Incoming Connection Request
PS3 Bluetooth Library Started
PS3 Bluetooth Library Started
Bluetooth Dongle Initialized
HCI Reset complete
Write class of device
Local Bluetooth Address: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:10
Wait For Incoming Connection Request
Incoming Connection Request
Remote Name: Pro Controller
Connection Failed: 08
Connection Failed: 08
```

Comment: yes I am trying to connect a ps3 controller only @jsotola. also I have one  old ps3 controller which is getting connected but this one doesn't. can you please suggest something. I am in desperate need of it

Comment: @jsotola sorry my mistake, I have made the changes in the question and now it says that I am trying to connect ps3 controller. thank you for suggesting changes. also please do suggest something. thanks

Comment: search for `arduino ps3 controller`